# How to remove newline from column values in Sybase

Tags: sql, regex, database, sap-ase

i have a table in sybase that has 7 columns.

The sixth column has a new line as the last character in all the values. This newline is messing up the output when i export the table. How can i remove the newline character from all values in this column ?

Comment: I would search for questions tagged with [sql] and [regex], as those will probably get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this did the trick

```
update tableName
set column_name =str_replace(column_name, char(13), null)
```

Comment: `UPDATE tableName
SET colName = REPLACE(colName, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), '')`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether the newline is in windows or unix format, one of the below should work:

```
UPDATE tableName SET column_name = str_replace(column_name, char(13), null)
```

or

```
UPDATE tableName SET column_name = str_replace(column_name, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '')
```